# Mobile experience of existing entries

Tags: forms, mobile, popup

**I have a form in a mobile layout.**

When users enter details into the form, **existing matches** will be checked for in the database, If there are any matches, they will appear below the form and they can select them instead. *(See diagram)*

[image]

This poses a bit of a UX issue in that the items could show below the fold and go completely unnoticed.
I don't want to encourage duplication, but I don't want to annoy my users by making the suggestions front and center either.

Does anyone have any ideas of where would be a good place to show suggestions in mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it show up as a scrollable drop-down menu. you can make it's height as responsive (e.g. 10% of height), this way it never goes beyond the screen. Make sure the user understands that they can scroll down the list. Use some sort of indicator to show that there's more, or even have the scrollbar flash (slowly, and once only) so that the user understands that they can scroll the list. You can also only show only the top 10 for example.